# How do I get the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables to have the header I specify

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, tocloft, naming

I used `\renewcommand\contentsname{\Large{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}` (similar for list of figures and list of tables) to obtain headers that were centered at the top of the page, not bold and capitalized. After using `\usepackage{tocloft}` these are bold, not centered and not fully capitalized. Also the font size has changed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Don't forget that you can up-vote good answers and also accept the ones you consider best solved your problems. Up-voting and accepting are two different actions. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{\Large{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
```

is wrong as the `\....name` macros are just supposed to have and (expandable) macro with the text to use to allow for localisation. A font command is not expandable so will not work in all contexts. If you were to put in a font command you should keep it local to the command, `\Large` does not take an argument so that is the same as

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{\Large TABLE OF CONTENTS}
```

and will make all following text Large as well to the end of whatever group encloses the use of `\contentsname`.

It's hard to give advice without a sample document, on particular information about the class being used. However the table of contents usuallu uses`\section*` or `\chapter*` depending on the class, so you should define

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
```

then use the package to make `section*` centred

I've not used tocloft but its documentation says

> `\renewcommand{\cftZtitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}` together with 
>   `\renewcommand{\cftafterZtitle}{\hfill}` will give a centered Large bold
>   title

So I assume you want (for Z=lot)

```
 \renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Large} 
 \renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
```

which is the same but without the `\bfseries`

Comment: Can you expound on \section* or \chapter*? I am getting the error messages \cftZtitlefont undefined and \cftafterZtitle undefined. There are changes in the output but they are not the changes I originally sought help for. Also, can you give an example of exactly what I am supposed to type ? Thank you.

Comment: Note that `Z` in the document should be substituted for the "List of ..." unit you're after. So, I'm guessing you're after `\cfttoctitlefont` and `\cftaftertoctitle` (as well as all the others; where `Z` is `lof` and `lot`).

Comment: Thanks @Werner and Carlisle the font is as requested. There is a follow up problem. The titles are now far below there original location at the top of the page.

Comment: @PeterPalmer Please ask a new question with a _complete_ small example document that shows the problem.