# How do I get the titles on the list of contents, list of tables and list of figures pages to be a specific height on the page?

Tags: table-of-contents

The titles on the pages for list of contents, list of tables and list of figures are not at the height that I want them to be. I need them to go further up on the page.  How do I do this?

Comment: Sure this is a follow-up question of [How do I get the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables to have the header I specify](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114709/5764), correct? If so, are you also requesting a solution with the use of [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)? And, are you using the same `\documentclass`?

Comment: Yes I am requesting a solution with the use of tocloft. I am using \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the vertical spacing before the titles using the lengths

```
\cftbeforeZtitleskip
```

where `Z` stands for `toc`, `lof`, or `lot`; a little example (change `-100pt` to the value that best suits your needs):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{-100pt}
\setlength\cftbeforeloftitleskip{-100pt}
\setlength\cftbeforelottitleskip{-100pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

This won't have any effect if the `titles` package option is being used.

Comment: Thank you @GonzaloM. I can now control the height of the titles on the pages specified.